# Images showing as broken when they shouldn't

Tags: javascript, html, image, broken-image

I do not understand why the images on my site shows up as broken, if you could have a quick look at: http://www.lamcallum.com Is there someone that can solve this mystery? Any replies would be appreciated...

UPDATE: Issue is resolved.

Comment: Have you looked at your source and tried going directly to the images in the source?  I would try this, but the proxy here blocks your site.

Comment: Yes I sure have, no problem there. I am certain that the problem is something javascript related or something similar that is preventing the images from being displayed...

Comment: it's beacuse of `<img src="">` is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `<img src="1pixelsquare1.gif"> //grey color image` then it will work perfectly fine.

---

Your Code for each box

```
   <div class='fade' onMouseOver="JSFX.fadeIn('button')" onMouseOut="JSFX.fadeOut('button')">
        <img name="button" class="imgFader" width="100" height="100" border="0">
     </a> //extra coded - remove it
   </div>
```

Every box Img should have the "src" like this

```
   <img name="button" class="imgFader" src="1pixelsquare1.gif" width="100" height="100" border="0">
```

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate, where and how should I add that?

Comment: Sorry this made perfect sense now. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that on initial load, your images do not have a source. Which would explain why they are broken. Once mouse-over-ed they do.

ETA: More detail. The image tags do not have anything in the src property. Either in code behind, the html you have coded or js. If you post your original code I can help more.

Comment: Sorry I am not very experienced programmer, would you mind telling me more in detail how I would address this issue?